# GWT 2.2 + JPA problem

Tags: java, gwt, jpa

I am working with GWT 2.2, JPA, Java EE 6 Web, glassfish v3.
My problem is that I receive the following error if I use my entity in an RPC call: "No source code is available for type entity.User; did you forget to inherit a required module?"

First I tought the problem was the annotation, but then I read that from GWT 2.0 version should be working if "The class is annotated with a JPA javax.persistence.Entity annotation".

So what can be the problem?

Ummm, I think I just write here everything.
I have the GWT project with the following packages:

`org.ecommunity`
`org.ecommunity.client` (and org.ecommunity.client.view)
`org.ecommunity.server` -> and here is just a service impl.:

```
public class ECommunityServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements ECommunityService  {
    @EJB
    ECommunitySB bean;

    @Override
    public User loginService(String username) {
        return bean.getUserByUsername(username);
    }
}
```

My `Main.gwt.xml` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 1.7.0//EN" "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.7.0/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">
<module>
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.User"/>
    <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard'/>
    <entry-point class="org.ecommunity.client.MainEntryPoint"/>
    <source path="client"/>
</module>
```

And I have an EJB Module with the following packages: 
`entity` (in here is my `User` entity class) and a `sessionbean` (with my sessionbean)

and if I add the `<source path='server' />` the problem is the same with this new one: "The import javax.ejb cannot be resolved. EJB cannot be resolved to a type."

Comment: Are you sure that source of your entities is available for GWT compiler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to delete your EJB Module and put the sessionbean and the entity class into the gwt projet. So now you have only 1 project. And you have to add the EclipseLink (JPA 2.0) library  to the classpath (because of the annotations).

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be missing a source path in your {project}.gwt.xml

```
<source path='yourpath' />
```

I'll take a guess here lets say your {project}.gwt.xml is located in

```
 org.ecommunity
```

There probably is a package

```
 org.ecommunity.client
```

With allready some GWT stuff which is what is included by `<source path='client' />`
but your entity classes are in: `org.ecommunity.server.entity` So you would have to put in another source for `<source path='server' />`. BTW it might be better to move the entities out from under server to a for instance `org.ecommunity.entity` and add `<source path='entity' />` because I guess that under server there is a lot of code that is not relevant for the client code.

Comment: I don't think that would be the problem. I have this: <source path="client"/>

Comment: I have expanded my answer to clarify some points hope it helps.

Comment: As said by Eelke, I usually keep common client and server code in another package which I tell GWT where to find it <source path='shared' />

Comment: I refreshed my question. Am I missing something? Should I do something with the entity in the client?

Comment: Or maybe am I still need to write DTO in 2.2?

Comment: My guess the GWT compiler is trying to compile your service implementation causing the error about import javax.ejb as that is not available at the client side. Try moving your entities to a shared package outside the server package and adjust the source in the xml accordingly.

Comment: In the GWT project I don't have entities.